# How to make jQuery show() stay on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I have two tables next to each other, the one on the right has an issue with the div displaying off the page when using show().

How can I prevent this?

```
    $("tr.invoice_head td:last-child a").hover(
        function(){$(".custNotes-span",this).position({
            of: '.custNotes-span',
            my: 'right top',
            at: 'right top',
            offset: '.custNotes-span'
        }).css({
            'z-index':'100',
            'width': '200px',
            'position':'absolute'}).show();},
        function(){$(".custNotes-span").hide();}
    );
```

Update: JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/r60ywb0L/2/

My apologies, here is a copy of the JSFiddle including the JS used and CSS. There's two tables floated next to each other and I'm trying to get a div.custNotes-span to display over the rest of the page when hovering over the anchored link inside the last td of the tr.invoice_head.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your HTML included?

Comment: Hard to tell without the HTML. But I assume it has to do with the fact that `show()` is setting `display: block` and that is messing up the layout. You could try instead of `show()` calling `css('display', 'inline-block')`.

Comment: check which table it is and perhaps use `left top` if it is second table. `if($(this).closest('#table2ID').length)...`

Comment: This is jQueryUI's `.position()` right? If so, (a) there's no mention in the documentation of `offset`, and (b) have you tried setting a `collision` option?

Comment: Another idea - try showing the element before positioning it. `$(".custNotes-span", this).show().position({...}).css({...})`

Comment: Updated, thank you very much about the heads up on the offset @Roamer-1888 I'll also try the CSS you suggested. I'll have to figure out what to use.

I've also updated the original post with a JSFiddle link, appreciate the suggestion and I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @Eric, you haven't included jQueryUI in the fiddle. I wonder if that's the issue in your dev copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing around in the fiddle, I found that :

- CSS needs to be applied before being positioned.
- The elements need to be rendered in the DOM when positioned (but not necessarily 'visible').
- The `of` property of the `position()` map is better set to the closest table row
- `collision:'fit'` seems to work better than the default `collision:'flip'`, though you may not notice the difference except in th fiddle.
- The elements can be positioned once. It's not necessary to re-position them at each showing.

The following workaround exploits CSS `visibility` to allow correct positioning while avoiding FOUC.

- apply .css() including `visibility:hidden`
- "show" with `.show()` (but still hidden)
- apply .position()
- hide with `.hide()`
- make "visible" with `visibility:visible` (but still hidden)

The elements can then be shown/hidden with `.show()` and `.hide()` in the hover handlers.

```
// As the positioning map and the css map get used in a loop, it's worth assigning them outside the loop.
var maps = {
    css: {
        'z-index': '100',
        'width': '200px',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'visibility': 'hidden'
    },
    pos: {
        'of': null, //added dynamically below
        'my': 'right top',
        'at': 'right top',
        'collision': 'fit'
    }
};

//Apply CSS and pre-position the notes
$(".custNotes-span").each(function() {
    $(this)
        .css(maps.css)
        .show()
        .position( $.extend({}, maps.pos, {'of': $(this).closest("tr")}) )
        .hide()
        .css('visibility','visible');
});

//The maps have done their work and can be deleted from the closure.
delete maps.css;
delete maps.pos;

//Hover actions
$(".custNotes a").hover(function() {
    $(".custNotes-span", this).show();
}, function() {
    $(".custNotes-span", this).hide();
});
```

Selectors are modified to be a bit more friendly.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7mdqn8nL/13/show/)**

Comment: This is by far the most helpful and best advice I've ever received on StackOverflow. Like I said before I'll brand new to jQuery and didn't even realize that order of the properties mattered. I'll definitely take a bit to digest everything and do diligent research to further understand more of the why behind your extremely helpful explanations; but you did a fantastic job talking me (and anybody else who reads this) through exactly why the changes you made were important. Very sincerely appreciated and hats off to you!

Comment: Also any resources you recommend for jQuery or just practice, practice, practice?

Comment: Many thanks for your kind comments. The only book I have on jQuery is [jQuery Pocket Reference by David Flanagan](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=jquery+pocket+reference&tag=googhydr-21&index=aps&hvadid=34729088148&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=5891366538417268591&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_21143qacxm_b). Although jQuery has undergone many changes since this book was published, the basics haven't changed and it covers them well. At just a few $s, it's a real bargain. Online, you can't do better than the official [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: Just one small point on what you said above, it is the order of *methods* in a method chain that (potentially) matters, not *properties*.

Comment: Gotcha, my apologies, good correction. One thing though is that it seems as if sometimes the custNotes-span top position is way higher on the page, could this be a side effect of the SMARTY templates? I tried moving the jQuery to near the end of the script instead of the top and it didn't work. Maybe I should have the elements rendered on show instead of before?

Comment: Smarty, in itself, is unlikely to be the cause 'cos it's server-side and the client (the browser) is blissfully unaware of how the server made the page. Of course the HTML generated by Smarty could be at fault, but that's a slightly different statement.